# Is there a way to select the first word/combo of characters in a string, separated by spaces?

Tags: php, string, explode

For instance, I'm trying to select the first word in this string:

```
"chocolate muffin"
```

So I want `"chocolate"`, but not the `" "` (space) and not the `"muffin"` text.

I imagine I could do `$separate = explode(" ",$string)`, and just take `$separate[0]`, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this?

Edit: This is in PHP.

Comment: Ah, sorry!  It's PHP language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more efficient, although a bit less readable in my opinion:

```
$mystring = substr($mystring, 0, strpos($mystring, " "));
```

This is because with `strpos` the search cycle stops to the first occurrence of the charachter, then it returns the given length of the string.

With explode, the search cycle goes til the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

can also write a slight variation ...

```
list($res) = explode(' ',$string);
```

Comment: you can see this style in the example for the documentation of explode at http://au2.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Nice. Just add a limit as the third parameter to stop the research cycle to the first occurrance. Then list($res) = explode(' ',$string, 1);

Answer (score 2):

```
$firstword = strtok($string," ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$first = strstr($string, ' ', true);
```

Please note that this will only work > PHP 5.3.

[PHP strstr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)